# How do I change the url of my web service that exists in a class library?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services

I have a class library that has a reference to a web service and I include this class library in my web.config.

Now I want to be able to dynamically change the url of the web service (like you would normally do in the web.config). How can I do this?  I tried putting the settings into the web.config, but changing it has no effect.

```
  <applicationSettings>
    <MyClassLibraryAppConfig.WCFServices.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="WebServiceKey"
        serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://localhost/badaddress.asmx</value>
      </setting>    
    </MyClassLibraryAppConfig.WCFServices.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>

  <applicationSettings>
    <MyApp.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="WebServiceKey"
        serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://localhost/goodaddress.asmx</value>
      </setting>    
    </MyApp.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the web service url to the host application's web.config is definitely the way to go in most cases. You mentioned that changing the value in the web.config file has no effect but I'd double-check that. Unless you have the url hard-coded, that's the location where the host process would read it from.

Comment: The url is set in the app.config of the class library... how can i prevent it from being hardcoded?

Comment: As long as you have an entry with the same key in the web.config then the app.config value is ignored. Just copy/paste it from the class library app.config to the host web.config.

Comment: I do have the same key.  I'll post an updated config in the question to show you.  Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @zachary you should copy/paste the entire <MyClassLibraryAppConfig.WCFServices.Properties.Settings> section to the web.config, not only the <setting> node as the Settings proxy class namespaces are different.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a web reference, then see [Ways to Customize your ASMX Client Proxy](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2008/06/05/ways-to-customize-your-asmx-client-proxy/). If you are using WCF, then you can use the overload of the proxy class constructor which includes an EndpointAddress.